# In C++, how can I declare a function that takes a vector array of any object as an agrument?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments, stdvector

For example, I have 3 different objects a, b, and c; each of which is an instance of a different class. I want to declare a function that will take a std::vector array as an argument; where the vector array is an array of objects a, b or c (not mixed). How can I do this?

My code:

```
//TODO: make this work for any vector array in the program;
bool assert_choice (std::vector<?> array) { //asserts that choice is valid 
    std::cout << "ohai" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure how to declare the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function template:

```
template< class T >
bool assert_choice( std::vector<T> array )
{
    //...
}
```

You might also consider passing by reference `std::vector<T> &` or `const std::vector<T> &`.

Comment: An iterator pair might be a good idea too. Then it could use any sequence container, not just a vector.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It's not completely clear what their intent is, but the question title states "any object", and there is no mention of restricting it to *only* types **A**, **B** and **C**.

Comment: @paddy: Ah, maybe.  The title says one thing, but the question body says "where the vector array is an array of objects a, b or c".  Who knows what the real requirements are...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Exactly.  So I've tried to solve their main problem and keep it simple until instructed otherwise =)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using `a`, `b`, `c` as examples and not the *only* types you want to pass, don't pass by vector but by iterator pair:

```
template <class Iter>
bool assert_choice (Iter first, Iter last) { ... }
```

With this approach, any type that meets the required interface can be passed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type trait for this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename V = void>
struct is_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_type<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, A>::value
                                       || std::is_same<T, B>::value
                                       || std::is_same<T, C>::value
              >::type
> : std::true_type {};
```

And change your class to take a template like this. That way it will only compile if `T` is the type `A`, `B` or `C`:

```
template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<is_type<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
bool assert_choice(std::vector<T>& var)
{
    // ...
    return true;
}
```